# Merge two GeoJSON into one in a dataframe

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, shapely, pandas

I have a dataframe containing GeoJSON:

```
   geojson                                       checkpoint    lom_name
    {"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[1,4],[2,5]]}   6   marathon19
    ("type":"LineString","coordinates":[[3,6],[4,7]]}   0   marathon19
```

The desired result is:

```
   geojson                                                             lom_name
    {"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[1,4],[2,5],[3,6],[4,7]]}      marathon19
```

I tried `df = df.groupby(['geojson']).apply(list)`   not really giving something i need

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete working code for your problem. First, I loaded geojson to geodataframe. Then, I iterated through each feature and check if lom_name matches to the one for which lines are being merged.

Then I created Shapely MultiLineString from array of LineStrings.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
import json
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import geometry


def merge_gdf(name):
    l_seg = json.loads("""
     {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "checkpoint": 6,
                "lom_name": "marathon19"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [1, 4],
                    [2, 5]
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "checkpoint": 0,
                "lom_name": "marathon19"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [3, 6],
                    [4, 7]
                ]
            }
        }, {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "checkpoint": 0,
                "lom_name": "marathon20"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "LineString",
                "coordinates": [
                    [6, 8],
                    [10, 12]
                ]
            }
        }]
    }
    """)
    line_segments = []
    gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(l_seg["features"])
    print(gdf.head())

    for idx, row in gdf.iterrows():
        if row['lom_name'] == name:
            line_segments.append(row['geometry'])

    multiline = geometry.MultiLineString(line_segments)
    print(multiline)

    gs = gpd.GeoSeries(multiline)
    print(gs.to_json())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    merge_gdf('marathon19')
```